# I am having trouble using the Jsoup library on my project

Tags: eclipse, jsoup

I downloaded the latest Jsoup and moved it to my workspace in finder. I then added it to the ClassPath thing under the Project Properties. However when I try and import Jsoup classes/packages in the code, I get an error that says the element cannot be resolved. Is there any other thing I should check to ensure that the software usable?

This is for an Eclipse project that I am using to practice scraping.

Comment: Do you have a `module-info.java` file in your default package? If yes, delete it (or learn about [JPMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System)). Otherwise, please show your project structure and configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I'll show you how I'm doing it and what's the result.
Adding Jsoup library to project:

[image]

Then it looks like this:

[image]

Then when I peek into my `.classpath` file it has a new line with jsoup path:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/jre1.8.0_161"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="F:/lib/jsoup/jsoup-1.12.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

This way every import to Jsoup classes is easily recognized and missing imports are resolved without problems.